# How to check the type of these three values with TypeScript interfaces?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

The following code often breaks because `label, description, details` have the wrong type.

So I want to make sure they are being fed the right arguments:

label should be `string`.

description should be `string or array of strings`.

details should be `string`.

This is my first time using TypeScript, so I checked the [official interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) docs. And included an interface:

```
const quickPick = vscode.window.createQuickPick()
const response = await fetch(`https://api.datamuse.com/words?ml=${text.replace(" ", "+")}`)
const data = await response.json() // [{"word": "close", "score": 123, "tags": ["n", "adj"]}

interface Item {
  label: string
  description: string[] || string
  detail: string
}

quickPick.items = data.map((item: Item) => {
  return {
    label: item.word,
    description: item.tags ? item.tags.join(', ') : 'no tags',
    detail: `Relevance: ${item.score.toString()}`
  }
})
```

However, Visual Studio Code is showing me a bunch of errors. So I'm assuming my code isn't even proper TypeScript code.

[image]

What's the correct way of doing this?

**Update:** I tried the suggestion below, but now I have this error:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "So I want to make sure they are being fed the right arguments: string, string or array of strings, string."?

Comment: `string[] | string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cartant mentioned in the comments, you [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) declaration is wrong, it should be separated by `|` instead of `||`

```js
interface Item {
  label: string;
  description: string[] | string;
  detail: string;
}
```

It also looks that the map's lambda definition is incorrect. You defined it as `(item: Item) => { ... }` which means that input parameter type is `Item`. But, I guess that you intended to return that type, so definition should look like: `(item): Item => { ... }`

```js
quickPick.items = data.map((item): Item => ({
  label: item.word,
  description: item.tags ? item.tags.join(', ') : 'no tags',
  detail: `Relevance: ${item.score.toString()}`
}))
```

I've also changed `() => { return { ... }; }` to `() => ({ ... })`, it's just a more convenient way to write such expression.

Comment: @alexchenco You're also accessing unexciting properties of the `Item` inside the `map`, like `item.word`. Should these properties be available via the interface, or it's just a mistake?

Comment: It's a mistake. What changes should I make then? I'm a bit confused, haha. Or maybe I shouldn't be using interfaces here?

Comment: @alexchenco I'm sorry, it looks like the function definitions was incorrect, so I misunderstood the code. I updated the answer, hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer was extremely useful.

Comment: Oh wait. Now there's this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj96a.png

Comment: @alexchenco I guess it's because `data` array item type isn't defined. If you don't have corresponding interface you can set it implicitly to `any`, like `(item: any): Item => ({ ... })`